# How to create UITextField to display text when editing UITextField covered by keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have created a messaging application with multiple text fields that exist int the bottom of the screen. Unfortunately, when I click to edit the text field the keyboard covers it up. I have done much searching and have come to the conclusion that the only way to move the text field is to incorporate a scroll view - something I did not do when developing the application. I figure the next best thing is to temporarily create a UITextField that rests on top of the keyboard that displays user input (the same input being entered into the real UITextField). I have not been able to find a good way to do this as I would need it to disappear once the keyboard is resigned. Can anyone suggest how I would go about doing this?
Thank you.
Nick

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1126726/1183577

Comment: You should move up the view.

Comment: You should consider using a scroll view and implementing Jacky's solution. I believe it will be the easiest way and save you a lot of UI coding. All you need to do is put your text fields in a scroll view and then subclass the scroll view as described in Jacky's link.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to embed your complete view into a scroll view and then bring the textfield above the keyboard programmatically when EditingBegin event occurs. There is a wonderful example explained in Apple's documentation [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW2) Please check the "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard" section of the mentioned documentation. It address your exact problem.